# What's going on with my program (openGL in c++)?

Tags: c++, opengl, camera, glut

I am starting with openGL and c++, and I was wondering why I don't see anything on the window. Here is my code:

```
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void init() {
    glClearColor(0, 0, 1, 0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60.0, 1.0, 1.0, 100.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0, 0, -10);
}

void display() {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex3i(-0.5, -0.5, 0);
    glVertex3i(0, 0.5, 0);
    glVertex3i(0.5, -0.5, 0);
    glEnd();
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE| GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(200, 200);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);
    glutCreateWindow("Window");

    init();

    glutDisplayFunc(display);


    glutMainLoop();
}
```

I have a few questions:

1. If I run the program like this all I see is a white window... Didn't I set the color to blue?
2. When I do `glutSwapBuffers()` at the end of display function and run the program, I see the blue window without the triangle. So, I thought `glutSwapBuffers()` function only worked with double buffering.
3. And the most important, where the hell is my triangle? O.o Didn't I translate the camera with `glTranslatf()` function to -10 in the z-axes? If you are wondering why I used gluPerspective, I have to say that I am trying out new things, but neither works if I use gluOrtho2D().

I don't know if I am missing something or what. Maybe I need to search more information about this, but I think most of the code is correct.

Comment: A very good idea would be a different question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 & 2) Well you don't have to call `glutSwapBuffers()` when using single buffer. But you have to call `glFlush()`, so the draw commands are executed on the GPU.

3) I noticed that you are creating vertices with double coordinates, but you are calling integer version of glVertex** function (decimal part will be truncated) - it means that you will be drawing triangle with zero size.

Use `glVertex3d()` or `glVertex3f()` instead of `glVertex3i()`.

Small note: intermediate mode is deprecated in the latest OpenGL.

Comment: Ok that answered the 3rd question! Thanks! But I only see the triangle if I do ´glutSwapBuffers()´ even if I am using a single buffer... Any ideas why?

Comment: Worked like magic! But can you explain me why did glutSwapBuffers() work if I was using single buffer?

Comment: It internally calls glFlush();

Comment: @Johny: Most likely you're on a operating system that uses a compositing graphics system. They've become the standard for over 6 years now. With a compositor essentially everything gets forcibly double buffered. The compositor needs some kind of wake up call, to inform it, that the picture is ready for presentation, which is essentially a copying buffer swap; and that is done by the BufferSwap call. To make a long story short: Single buffered operating has become rather useless these days. So don't bother using it.